# FreeForm Pro form with "add another row" field

Tags: solspace-freeform, javascript, solspace

I'm creating a form where a user can add named people with a Name, Address, Phone and Email. There's also a javascript in place that allows a user to add another row/person. When they click this, it reveals another set of fields for Name, Address, Phone and Email for the second person and so on.

My question is how would I then get this submitted into the form in the Control Panel?

I was wondering if anyone has built anything like this before?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you place a limit on the number of such rows the user may add?

Comment: No, in theory they can add as many as they like. But in reality people will only ever add 2 or 3.

Comment: Sounds like you really want a matrix-like fieldtype within your form, which I don't think Freeform would be able to do. Maybe they'll chime in with another solution, but all i can think of is your having to create a set of fields for each possible address the user may add, postfixed with a number (postfixing the fields on the front end of your form when a new row is added). So address_1, city_1, address_2, city_2, etc. and create as many of those sets as you might envision a user adding.  Certainly not ideal, but out of the box, certainly possible.

Comment: Thanks Jean. This was my thought also. A tedious approach but it would work.

Comment: It's certainly not ideal, but it may be the most straight forward approach.

Answer (score 2):

Two possible strategies come to mind for this:

- As another user suggested, create as many Name, Address, Phone and Email fields as you need or think will need, and add a suffix for each field name (eg. `name_1`, `name_2`, etc)
- If you're manually creating your fields in the template using `{exp:freeform:form}`, add brackets `[]` to your field names so that you save the data as an *array* of data. Eg.

  `Name: <input type="text" name="name[]" />
  Name: <input type="text" name="name[]" />
  // etc...`

For #2, this will however store all data in a single custom field, separated by a linebreak (**not** `<br />`, by the way). For example, in the "name" field in the CP you would have the following stored for three names entered:

```
Curly
Larry
Moe
```

You'll need PHP to break those apart if you need them later (using PHP's `explode()` function or a third-party plugin that does something similar).

Comment: Thank you. We're using regular text form fields and storing them in hidden values right through to the final submit page. At that point i'm using the freeform:form to pass all the hidden values into the the CP. It wouldn't actually be too much of an issue if the name and address data was passed to a single textarea field in the CP.